# Inequality with and absolute values

Tags: inequality, logic

I'm having some troubles doing the logic of some inequalities with absolute values. I'm suppose to show knowing
$$ |x-a| < r, \quad |y-b| < r $$
and
$$ r \leq a-1, \quad r \leq 2-a, \quad r \leq b-1, \quad r \leq 3-b $$
will conclude that
$$ 1<x<2, \quad 1<y<3. $$

But i'm getting confused. Looking just at $x$ and $a$ i'm trying to insert the values for $r$:
$$ |x-a| < r$$
and 
$$ r \leq a-1, \quad r \leq 2-a $$
$$ \Rightarrow a-1 > |x-a| < 2-a.$$

But now i don't know what to do to get $1<x<2$. 
Would love your suggestions... Off ourse the author even mocks me and writes it's easy... dang

Comment: $|x−a|<r$ is $-r < x−a <r$. This is: $a-r < x < r+a$.

Comment: Ahh i see. thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and get rid of the absolute value to start
$$
|x-a|<r\implies a-r<x<a+r
$$
ok now bound below 
$$
1\leq a-r
$$
since $r\leq a-1$ means $-r\geq -a+1$.

For the second inequality, use that 
$$
r\leq 2-a\implies r+a\leq 2
$$
to find 
$$
1<x<2
$$

Comment: I see! thank you @qbert

Comment: No problem. And pay no heed to these sorts of comments in books, it often just means they have more experience than you

Comment: I like that approach :D